# The requested URL /symfony/web/index.php/auth/login showing error 404 - Page not found

Tags: symfony

Although I didn't make any change on my code but showing error while accessing orange hrm page like "The requested URL  /symfony/web/index.php/auth/login showing error 404 - Page not found!"

I will be highly thankful if anyone suggest a solution for this.
My server is hostgator
Php version 5.4

Comment: In Symfony, there's no `index.php` file. It should be `app.php` or `app_dev.php`. Isn't that your mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the webserver is not setup correctly. /symfony/web/index.php seems like a file on your system, /auth/login would probably be an argument to it. The redirection is not setup properly.
Depending on your webserver you'll have to look up the config.
See the following for nginx:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/symfony/